# Window function query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, dense-rank

We have columns Date, CID, Budget. We want to create a column Budget_rank which gives us result as:
Observe that the resultant table looks sorted on date first and then whichever same Budget values were there, they got the same rank

Expected Output:

| Date | CID | Budget | Budget_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-24 | 123 | 12500 | 1 |
| 2022-05-23 | 123 | 12500 | 1 |
| 2022-05-16 | 123 | 12500 | 1 |
| 2022-05-15 | 123 | 9800 | 2 |
| 2022-05-13 | 123 | 9800 | 2 |
| 2022-05-12 | 123 | 8400 | 3 |
| 2022-05-08 | 123 | 8400 | 3 |
| 2022-05-04 | 123 | 15600 | 4 |
| 2022-05-02 | 123 | 15600 | 4 |

Can anyone please assist with the SQL query that may help us generate this column budget_rank.?

What I tried is:

```
SELECT 
  Date, 
  CID, 
  Budget, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Budget)
FROM table;
```

But this dint gave us the expected output!

I need to make sure that the Budget_rank column is generated, exactly in the same fashion as shown in the table above. Any help with the query or direction will really help. TIA.

Comment: Schematically: ```SUM(value <> LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) OVER (ORDER BY Date)```. Of course, CTE needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `LAG()` window function to get the previous `Budget` of each row and create a boolean flag of 1 or 0 depending on whether the previous `Budget` is different than the current `Budget` and then sum over the flags to create the column `Budget_rank`:

```
SELECT Date, CID, Budget,
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY Date DESC) Budget_rank
FROM (
  SELECT *, Budget <> LAG(Budget, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY Date DESC) flag
  FROM tablename
) t
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ywiKsn8GkauW9tgCx1m64/1).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. This is throwing an error: "No matching signature for analytic function LAG for argument types : STRING, INT64, INT64. Supported signature : LAG(ANY, [INT64], [ANY])

Comment: @Annu You can see in the demo link that I provide inside my answer that the syntax is correct. Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score 1):

You can't approach this problem with a `DENSE_RANK` function, as your ranking does not follow a specific order of budgets. What you can instead do is using a variable that assigns a value until a new budget is encountered. You check for new budget using the `LAG` window function:

```
SET @ranking = 0;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           LAG(Budget) OVER(PARTITION BY CID) AS LastBudget
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Date_,
       CID,
       Budget,
       IF(LastBudget = Budget,
          @ranking, 
          @ranking := @ranking +1
       ) YourRanking
FROM cte
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jxpYhcnNzrJSp4u96sP7KB/0).